# Can mosaic dataset be used as input to ArcGIS Pro's Image Classification Wizard?

Tags: spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, mosaic-dataset, image-classification

I am currently not licensed for the Image Analyst or Spatial Analyst extensions of ArcGIS Pro.  However, I am contemplating trialling/purchasing Spatial Analyst to perform image classification on a mosaic dataset.

I have been reviewing ArcGIS Pro Help pages like:

- [Overview of image classification](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/image-analyst/overview-of-image-classification.htm);
- [The Image Classification Wizard](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/image-analyst/the-image-classification-wizard.htm); and
- [Mosaic datasets](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/mosaic-datasets.htm)

but have not been able to find anything that says whether a mosaic dataset can be used as input to ArcGIS Pro's Image Classification Wizard.

If you know that it can, then can you point me at an ArcGIS Pro Help page that confirms it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem to do image classification on mosaic dataset as you can see in the in [Complete list of ArcGIS Image Analyst extension functions and tools](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/image-analyst/a-complete-listing-of-image-analyst-functions-and-tools.htm)

> **Maximum Likelihood Classify**: Performs a maximum likelihood
>   classification on a raster dataset or **mosaic dataset**.

But the above requires [Image Analyst extension](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/image-analyst/what-is-the-arcgis-pro-image-analyst-extension-.htm) which requires Image Analyst license, but I think Image classification under Spatial Analyst may do the same job, but at this point I am not sure. However, looking at the Image Analyst functions and tools they look similar to what exist in Spatial Analyst extension.